# Python, can not parse pintrest

Tags: python, parsing

I need to parse Pinterest, but for some reason, instead of links to pictures, incomprehensible and non-working links appear.

```
def parse():
    url = 'https://www.pinterest.ie/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    print(soup.find_all('a'))
parse()
```

Comment: Have you LOOKED at the source code for that page, using View Source or by printing out `r.text`?  The HTML you fetch contains little more than ads.  The page is built dynamically with Javascript.  You'd need to use something like Selenium to get a real browser involved.

Answer (score 0):

The site requires JavaScript to be active, which isn't the case when you send a request through BeautifulSoup. A workaround has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33120109/3730626), where you can use Selenium to open up the page in an actual browser (thereby enabling JavaScript), and then use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML.

Something like this should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
from selenium import webdriver

service = service.Service("../chromedriver.exe")
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)

def parse():
    url = 'https://www.pinterest.ie/'
    driver.get(url)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    print(soup.find_all('a'))

parse()
```

You will, of course, need some idea of how to use Selenium. The [official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) should help.